# How to change parameters in javascript function written in html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have some function in html code.

```
<span id='test' onclick="test("1", "2")">Click Me</span>
```

after executing i need to replace this function by other  with other parameters. can you advice if it is any opportuity to write this function not by eventlistener, but as html-attribute with the aim to see this function as html code, delete this

```
onclick="test("1", "2")
```

and add new one dynamically in html code

```
onclick="test("3", "4")
```

Comment: You can do it something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QXdG3/ (or alternatively: http://jsfiddle.net/QXdG3/1/)

Comment: Your request is a little specific and odd.  Why do you want to do it that way?  You probably don't need to rewrite the onclick attribute.  Your questions sounds a little like you have made a guess at what you need to do.  It would probably better if you instead described in a more general sense what you are wanting to achieve.

Comment: Jared Farrish - no, if do this way, function will not ne rewritten in html. I need onclick will be rewritten, for example as work setAttribute function and then work with new parameters. maybe it is impossible?

Comment: BigBadaboom - i need visual control how parameters will be changed. In html code it is easy to check.

Comment: I don't understand what your requirement is.

Comment: Jared Farrish i need <span id='test' onclick="test("1", "2")">Click Me</span> will be repaced <span id='test' onclick="test("3", "4")">Click Me</span> in html code and after click work with new parameters

Comment: The *in html code* doesn't make any sense. You don't *need* any *html code* to do what you want to do.

Comment: Jared Farrish, javascript can dynamically change class in html, make new attributes, can add or remove divs, add or remove childs but can not replace events as html-attribute? is it right?

Comment: I showed you how to do it in the first comment.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to change the attribute (as long as it can be represented as a string) or reference a global variable.

```
<span id='test' onclick="test(window.globalVar1, window.globalVar2)">Click Me</span>
```

However this probably shouldn't be done. It would be better to have test() call a function with your parameters.

```
var actualFunction = function() { // your actual function }
var wrapper = function() { actionFunction.apply(null, arrayOfArgs); }
```

Then the html-

```
<span id='test' onclick="wrapper()">Click Me</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Beginning, you have a syntax problem (You cannot use " in attribute value), change your HTML:

```
<span id='test' onclick="test('1', '2')">Click Me</span>
```

You change attribute onclick by jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#test').attr('onclick',"alert('3','4')");
});
```

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LACqP/

Enjoy your code!

Answer (score 0):

If your must intrude your html with javascript then here:

**HTML**

```
<span id='test' onclick="test()">Click Me</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Note: This script must go before the html unless you have a onDocReady
var testA = 1,
    testB = 2;

function test () {
    // use testA & testB for testing
    ...
    // test is over increment them
    testA++;
    testB++;
}
```